# canvas inside a div - position issues with css3

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I have this HTML:

```
<div id=test>
<canvas  id="pic" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

When I try to define the width and height through css (deleting the width and height attributes from the HTML element) like this:

```
#pic{
width:300px;
height:250px;
}
```

In this case, the picture is getting stretched - why?

When I try to add some other CSS properties to the `div` such as:

```
#test{
float:right;
border:solid red;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888;
}
```

I am getting the picture (or as matter of fact the canvas) tight to the top left corner, and from some reason the "box" that been created around the picture is a bit more larger than the picture itself.

I have tried to move the canvas inside the `div` with all sorts of `margin` and `padding` but it didn't move it inside the "box", the way that I wanted.

So, is there any way to move the canvas so it will be in the middle of the "box", or alternatively, a way to make the box smaller?

### New Addition

Starting with the first problem - here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

      <script>
          function myImage() {
              var context = document.getElementById('pic').getContext('2d');

              var img = new Image();
              img.src = "saturn-400x300.jpg";

              img.onload = function () {

                      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 250);
                  }
              
          }

    </script>
    
    <style>
        #pic {
        width:300px;
        height:250px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
   
  
    
<body onload="myImage()">

    <div id="test">
<canvas  id="pic" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now, in this situation the picture is fine - because of the inline attributes.  Here's how it looks:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/308b72s.jpg]

But when i remove the attributes from the inline, and leaving only the style - here's how it looks:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/2ntbxw5.jpg]

Now, about the second issue.leave   I left the inline attributes just to explain what I am talking about.  I added to the style tag the next code to the `div`:

```
   #test{
float:right;
border:solid red;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888;
}
```

and it now looks like:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/209sx93.jpg]

The white space between the red border and the picture(canvas) is what I am trying to eliminate.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean? Link to the website perhaps?

Comment: Or even better as jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a reset css file. It may be caused by browser defaults. If so, open your website in another browser, and check it out there.

Comment: Well i have tried in both chrome and firefox - but it's sure the same thing in both of them.

Comment: Have you tried to use are reset css file? I had a similar situation and it worked well when i used a reset css.